# how to create two new lists from an existing mysql db in random order in PHP where the elements at the same positions are unequal?

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

Ok. Let's make it all a little clearer.

What I am trying to do is the following:

I have a table like this one...

```
    +---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    |    id   |    name            | email                    |
    +---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    | 1       |  karl              | karl@email.com           |
    +---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    | 2       |  fred              | fred@email.com           |
    +---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    | 3       |  christopher       | chris@email.com          |
    +---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

What I want to end up with is a new table like the following:

```
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | id  | name1         | email1              | name2        | email2             |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 1   | fred          | fred@email.com      | christopher  | chris@email.com    |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 2   | christopher   | chris@email.com     | karl         | karl@email.com     |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 3   | karl          | karl@email.com      | fred         | fred@email.com     |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

The values are unique horizontally (id[1].name1 != id[1].name2) and vertically (id[1].name1 != id[2].name1).

Therefore, this output should not be possible:

```
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | id  | name1         | email1              | name2        | email2             |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 1   | fred          | fred@email.com      | christopher  | chris@email.com    |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 2   | fred          | fred@email.com      | karl         | karl@email.com     |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    | 3   | karl          | karl@email.com      | karl         | karl@email.com     |
    +-----+---------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

How can I achieve this in an easy way?

Comment: I can figure out how to make name1 != name2, and get all different name1's, but I can't figure out how to make sure all the name2's are different at the same time in a simple SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should do the work:

```
SELECT id1.name AS name1, id1.email AS email1, id2.name AS name2, id2.email AS email2
FROM table AS id1
JOIN table AS id2 ON ( name1 != name2 ) 
WHERE name1 < name2
```

where *table* is name of your table. I hope it'll help.